# find the longest common prefix string amongst an array of strings. If there is no common prefix, return an empty string ""

Tags: python, list, substring

find the longest common prefix string amongst an array of strings.
If there is no common prefix, return an empty string ""
I have tried to code this problem

here is code:

```
class Solution:
    def longestCommonPrefix(self, strs: List[str]) -> str:
        a=list(list(zip(*strs))[0])
        b=list(list(zip(*strs))[1])
        c=list(list(zip(*strs))[2])
        a1=""
        i=0
        while(len(strs)):
            if(a[i]==b[i]==c[i]):
                a1+=a[i]
                return a1
```

I have tried to solve via extracting element from the list and then comparing with other elements.

Don't know where it got struck no output is showing,
please help!

Comment: Do you have an example of some input data?

Comment: This is not a Python based question, You are trying to find what is the logic.And also provide some sample input and output

Comment: `while(len(strs))` will loop forever, since you're not doing anything with `strs` inside the while-loop. Also, `i` is unused and will always be `0`, which will probably result in a wrong output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

because `len(strs)` is always True,Your program is stuck in an infinite loop.
Another problem is that you only extracted the first three elements of each string in the string list, but the length of the largest common string may be greater than three elements

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way possible would be to start building a diet.
Iterate over all the strings and capture the first character of all the strings
Add them to the dict with count 1 and key as first character
If duplicates are found increment the count on the dict key
Now find the largest number in values of dict and store in a variable

Now repeat the procedure for 2 characters build dict with 2 character keys with starting value as 1 and increment the number if duplicate 2 characters are found in list of strings and replace the previous variable value with the highest value from recent dict

Repeat the procedure by incrementing the number of characters to be checked until you get 1 as the highest value in dict, and that value's key is the longest common prefix